# when to analyze full data set vs. residuals

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression

Say I have a data set, and I want to model the dependent variable `y`, as a function of `x1`,`x2`,`x3` and `x4`. I specify my model as:

```
y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x1*x2
```

I specify an interaction between `x1` and `x2` based on prior knowledge. However, the r2 value of the single regression model `y ~ x1` is ~0.90. Is it fair to still test for this interaction, as well as effects of `x2` and `x3` on `y`? Or is it better to do an analysis of the residuals of the model `y~x1`? The problem I forsee with the analysis of the residuals is that it can only test for a main effect of `x2` on `y`, it cannot test for an interaction with `x1`. Any thoughts on how to best handle this type of problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think it might not be "fair" to test for an interaction or the other main effects beyond $x_1$? And why do you think you can't examine residuals in a model with an interaction term? Quality control of regressions typically involves a plot of residuals against fitted values based on all predictors in the model.

Comment: I understand how 'qc' of model regression works. I do believe you can plot residuals vs fitted to examine heteroscedasticity, and examine qqnorm plots, etc. I mean taking the residuals of the model `y~ x1` and modeling them as a function of `x2 + x3 + x4`. In terms of 'fairness' I mean, is the relationship between `y` and `x1` too strong to warrant coding interactions, or is some other type of analysis more appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no magical cutoff for an $r^2$ value in regression (except maybe for 1.000), and what's an extraordinarily good fit in a biological study might be absurdly poor in a physics experiment. Unless your sole interest is in doing predictions of $y$ based on $x_1$ values and you have no remaining interest in how the other variables work together with $x_1$ to influence $y$, you still have some work to do and some variance to explain.

If, based on prior knowledge of your subject matter, you expect an interaction between $x_1$ and $x_2$ then you certainly should include that in your model, along with a main effect of $x_2$. If subject-matter knowledge indicates that $x_3$ and $x_4$ also influence $y$, include them too.

The multiple regression will be informative whether the other variables are correlated with $x_1$ or not. If they aren't, they may improve the fit even further. If they are, the nature of the interrelations might help inform your understanding of the underlying processes.

Comment: Thanks EdM. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't throwing up red flags looking for an interaction on a fit that is otherwise already pretty strong.